# Regex to capture between two words, and then within that result

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following text:

```
"BOONS": ["Debarrier+Rainbow Shift"
},
"CLUTCH_BOONS": [
  "Boost+Wall"
],
```

Regex:

```
(?<=[A-Z a-z])(\+)(?=[A-Z a-z])/g
```

Using That I am capable of capturing all of the +'s which is great, but I only want to capture the + signs inside of "CLUTCH_BOONS", I have tried really hard with little success.

I also want to close the "BOONS" bracket, I managed to get the left side going properly but cannot get the right quote

```
(?<=.*)(\")(?=.*\})
```

end result should look like this

```
"BOONS": ["Debarrier","Rainbow Shift"]
},
"CLUTCH_BOONS": [
  "Boost","Wall"
],
```

(I was trying to use Atom / regexr to fix problematic json)

Comment: If you only want to to capture the `+` signs inside of `"CLUTCH_BOONS"` why `+`s outside of this block is modified in expected result?

Comment: I tried making two regex, one to fix the bracket issue, and the other to create ","

Comment: *but I only want to capture the + signs inside of "CLUTCH_BOONS"* this is against your desired output.

Comment: I figured it might be easier and more logical to split the problem, the bottom part is my desired result

Comment: Try `(\[|\G(?!\A))([^]}+]*)\+` to replace `+` with `","`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/QKEVrn/1

Comment: Then you can do `\[(?:(?!\s*},)[\s\S])*\K(\s*},)` to close bracket. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/y3zqTw/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the plus signs, you can use this regex:

```
"\w+": \[\s*"\w+\K\+
```

see here:

> https://regex101.com/r/fJSl37/1

and for the second one:

```
"(\s*)},
```

see here:

> https://regex101.com/r/Oy0CiJ/1